# Retrieving JSON from URL on Android

Tags: android, json

My phone APP downloads content perfectly in a text mode. Below is a code to do that. I call Communicator class and exectueHttpGet:

`URL_Data = new Communicator().executeHttpGet("Some URL");`

```
public class Communicator {
public String executeHttpGet(String URL) throws Exception 
{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try 
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "android");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        request.setURI(new URI(URL));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";

        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        String page = sb.toString();
        //System.out.println(page);
        return page;
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (in != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                in.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e)    
            {
                Log.d("BBB", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

What I recive is this (source code of URL):

```
[{"id_country":"3","country":"AAA"},{"id_country":"8","country":"BBB"},
{"id_country":"66","country":"CCC"},{"id_country":"14","country":"DDD"},
{"id_country":"16","country":"EEE"},{"id_country":"19","country":"FFF"},
{"id_country":"24","country":"GGG"},{"id_country":"33","country":"HHH"},
{"id_country":"39","country":"III"},{"id_country":"44","country":"JJJ"},
{"id_country":"45","country":"KKK"},{"id_country":"51","country":"LLL"},
{"id_country":"54","country":"MMM"},{"id_country":"55","country":"NNN"},
{"id_country":"57","country":"OOO"},{"id_country":"58","country":"PPP"},
{"id_country":"63","country":"RRR"},{"id_country":"65","country":"SSS"}]
```

This response is a String. On server it is outputted (with PHP) as JSON object and now in my Android PHP I want to transfrom this string to JSON. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you receive is a series of characters from the `InputStream` that you append to a `StringBuffer` and convert to `String` at the end - so the result of `String` is ok :)

What you want is to post-process this String via `org.json.*` classes like

```
String page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet("Some URL");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(page);
```

and then work on `jsonObject`. As the data you receive is an array, you can actually say

```
String page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet("Some URL");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(page);
for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length(); i++ ) {
  JSONObject entry = jsonArray.get(i);
  // now get the data from each entry
}
```

Comment: `try {URL_Data = new Communicator().executeHttpGet("some url");
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(URL_Data);
} catch (Exception e) { Log.d("AAAA", "Napaka " + e.toString()); }` After trying this the debuger says: `04-07 08:44:54.719: DEBUG/AAAA(370): Napaka org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id_country":"3","country":"AAA"},{"id_country":"8","country":"BBB"},...] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: What I meant was to further process the string 'page' that you return from the posted method above.

Comment: Yes absolutely... It is just what I do...  **new Communicator().executeHttpGet("some url")** in the code above returns the value page. It is a string (see question - top of the page) and now I have no clue how to make it usable...

Comment: Ok, sorry - I misunderstood you.

Comment: I got it .. it works now the problem was in emulator... it crushed for unknown reason... Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `JSONObject entry = jsonArray.get(i);` I have `JSONObject entry = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

To further the question I linked you to earlier, use this example. put it in a function that returns a JSONArray (so then you can loop through the array and use array.getString). This works for most amounts of data. It will send the correct compression headers to the web server and detect a gzip compressed result also. Try it:

```
    URL url = new URL('insert your uri here');
    HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    httpConn.connect();
    if (httpConn.getContentEncoding() != null) {
        String contentEncoding = httpConn.getContentEncoding().toString();
        if (contentEncoding.contains("gzip")) {
        in = new GZIPInputStream(httpConn.getInputStream());
        }
        // else it is encoded and we do not want to use it...
    } else {
        in = httpConn.getInputStream();
    }
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(1000);
    int read = 0;
    int bufSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
    while (true) {
        read = bis.read(buffer);
        if (read == -1) {
        break;
        }
        baf.append(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    queryResult = new String(baf.toByteArray());
    return new JSONArray(queryResult);
```

**/End Edit**

Try reading the solution I posted on this SO question:

[Create list in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160291/create-list-in-android-app/5160613#5160613)

Hth,

Stu

Comment: Hi, those are just small requested data from server. Basically majority is stored on first lunch on phone's DB. The dynamic part (which is changing daily) is loaded on request. But what I want is to convert received string (like the one in question a the top of the page) to be used in Android Platform...

Comment: See my edited answer. It will work for your solution for small and large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

use org.json.JSONObject as in

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(oage);
```

thing to watch out for is when the response is simply "true" or "false."  probably want to create a util function that checks for those cases, otherwise just load up the JSONObject.

ok in this case you would use a JSONArray

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(page); 
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i) {
  JSONObject element = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  ..... 
}
```

Comment: Response on this server is either a string or blank and that is the way I check if data exists. String always represents JSON created by PHP (example is above). The only question is how to handle it now...

Comment: okay for this you need JSONArray and iterate thru with for loop:

`JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(URL_Data);`
`for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i) {`
`    JSONObject element = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);`
`.....`
`}`

Comment: i dunno how to format the comment correctly, but basically you load up the array, check its length, and use getJSONObject on the JSONArray

Comment: I got it .. it works now the problem was in emulator... it crushed for unknown reason... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the content type to `application/json`?

Comment: This will help the client to detect that this is Json data, but will not automagically turn the stuff into Json.

Comment: Well no.. The point is that I only receive a string as written above.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we have a POJO class called **Post**

```
public List<Post> getData(String URL) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    //This has to be AsyncTask because data streaming from remote web server should be running in background thread instead of main thread. Or otherwise your application will hung while connecting and getting data.
    AsyncTask<String,String, List<Post>> getTask = new AsyncTask<String,String,List<Post>>(){
        @Override
        protected List<Post> doInBackground(String... params) {
            List<Post> postList  = new ArrayList<Post>();
            String response = "";
            try{
                //Read stream data from url START
                java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
                        url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader reader = new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    response += line + "\n";
                }
                //Read stream data from url END

                //Parsing json data from reponse data START
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                    String message = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("message");
                    // Post class has a constructor which accept message value.
                    postList.add(new Post(message));
                }
                //Parsing json data from reponse data END
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return postList;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }
    };
    //This will return a list of posts
    return getTask.execute(URL).get();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

### just try like

///...

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString);

for(JSONObject jsonObject:jsonArray)
     {
      .........
      }

////..

Comment: Tried like this: `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(URL_Data); for(JSONObject jsonObject:jsonArray) {}` but got error: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable