# JSON Parsing Manifest Unreadable

Tags: android, json

So I wanted to parse Json File from a site that looks like this:

> {
>       "tnum": "12805",
>       "tname": "JANMABHOOMI EXP",
>       "tdate": "25-2-2013",
>       "from": "GNT",
>       "to": "SC",
>       "class": "CC",
>       "charted": true,
>       "numofpax": 2,
>       "pax": [{
>               "coach": "D2",
>               "berth": "23",
>               "quota": "GN",
>               "status": "CNF"
>           }, {
>               "coach": "S2",
>               "berth": "43",
>               "quota": "GN",
>               "status": "CNF"
>           }
>       ] }

Here's the incomplete code I wrote :

```
EditText num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pnr_num);
                     String numPNR= num.getText().toString();
                     url = "http://www.railpnrapi.com/";
                     url = url.concat(numPNR);
                     TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                     t.setText(url);

                    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(url);
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // grabbing the menu object 
                    try {
                        String id = jsonObj.getString("tname");
                        TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        t1.setText(id);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

However every time my app crashes. I even added network access permission !

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Where did I make a mistake? thanks. 
P.S. here's the site I am trying to access with a sample input :

> http://www.railpnrapi.com/6520652825

Comment: Can you provide the logcat or any stack trace?

Comment: @mbanzon Here it  is: http://pastebin.com/LZxFNVK8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create the `JSONObject` from an URL-string passed to the constructor and that will not work.

You need to fetch the content of the URL to a `String` and then pass that string to the `JSONObject` contructor.

Please refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577857/retrieving-json-from-url-on-android) for some detailed info. on how to do this.