# how to get Json array From website url in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing university online result check android app so that as the student enters his/her registration number in textbox the result shoud display. I have university url but I dont know how to extract that url in json format and call it to android Please Any one help me how to extract data from url in android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving JSON from URL on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577857/retrieving-json-from-url-on-android)

Comment: Thank you very much i will try this. Is this possible to create our own button and textbox to check result. i am newbie to android

Answer (score 1):

call JSONLoadTask().execute(yourUrl);

```
public class JSONLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    //your code
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject object = jParser.getJsonObject(params[0]);
         return object;
        }

      @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       //get the values from result here
       }

    }

}
```

take the below class

```
public class JSONParser {

        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        public JSONParser() {
        }

        /**
         * This method is used to parse the Url by taking the url as parameter
         * 
         * @param url
         * @return
         */
        public Object getJsonObject(String url) {
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(httpParams, false);
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 15000);
                httpGet.setParams(httpParams);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    try {
                        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                    }
                    if (json.startsWith("[")) {
                        // We have a JSONArray
                        try {
                            jObj = new JSONObject();
                            jObj.put("data", new JSONArray(json));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.d("JSON Parser",
                                    "Error parsing JSONArray " + e.toString());
                        }
                        return jObj;
                    }
                    // return JSON String
                    return jObj;
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 return null;
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               return null;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Hareesh, i tried this method but not able to get the answer, because website URL displays in ip format.

Comment: Thank you Hareesh , i will try.  is this code convert web url into json format,for example if my url is www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: where to call that JSONLoadTask().execute(yourUrl);

Comment: in ur activity or fragment

Comment: i got low reputation. I am still not able to get the desired result,may i know your mail_id